# Cosmos db null value

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two kind of record mention below in my table staudentdetail of cosmosDb.In below example previousSchooldetail  is nullable filed and it can be present for student or not.

sample record below :-

```
{
    "empid": "1234",
    "empname": "ram",
    "schoolname": "high school ,bankur",
    "class": "10",
    "previousSchooldetail": {
        "prevSchoolName": "1763440",
        "YearLeft": "2001"
    } --(Nullable)
}

{
    "empid": "12345",
    "empname": "shyam",
    "schoolname": "high school",
    "class": "10"
}
```

I am trying to access the above record from azure databricks using pyspark or scala code .But when we are building the dataframe reading it from cosmos db it does not bring previousSchooldetail detail in the data frame.But when we change the query including id for which the previousSchooldetail show in the data frame .

```
Case 1:-

    val Query = "SELECT * FROM c "

    Result when query fired directly
    empid
    empname
    schoolname
    class
    
Case2:-
    val Query = "SELECT * FROM c where c.empid=1234"
   
    Result when query fired with where clause.
    empid
    empname
    school name
    class
    previousSchooldetail
    prevSchoolName
    YearLeft
```

Could you please tell me why i am not able to get `previousSchooldetail` in case 1 and how should i proceed.

Comment: Case 1:-
    val Query = "SELECT * FROM c "
    Result when query fired directly
    empid
    empname
    schoolname
    class
    
    Case2:-
    val Query = "SELECT * FROM c where c.empid=1234"
   
    Result when query fired with where clause.
    empid
    empname
    school name
    class
    previousSchooldetail
    prevSchoolName
    YearLeft
     
     Could you please tell me why i am not able to get previousSchooldetail in case 1 and how should i proceed.

Comment: Case 1: will give the full doucments, in your case it will give the previouschooldetail too. I tried the same and it give the full documents

Answer (score 0):

As @Jayendran, mentioned in the comments, the first query will give you the `previouschooldetail` document wherever they are available. Else, the column would not be present.

You can have this column present for all the scenarios by using the `IS_DEFINED` function. Try tweaking your query as below:

```
SELECT c.empid,
       c.empname, 
       IS_DEFINED(c.previousSchooldetail) ? c.previousSchooldetail : null  
                 as previousSchooldetail,
       c.schoolname, 
       c.class
FROM c
```

If you are looking to get the result as a flat structure, it can be tricky and would need to use two separate queries such as:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT c.empid,
       c.empname,
       c.schoolname,
       c.class,
       p.prevSchoolName,
       p.YearLeft
FROM c JOIN c.previousSchooldetail p
```

**Query 2**

```
 SELECT c.empid,
        c.empname,
        c.schoolname,
        c.class, 
        null as prevSchoolName,
        null as YearLeft
 FROM c
 WHERE not IS_DEFINED (c.previousSchooldetail)  or 
           c.previousSchooldetail = null
```

Unfortunately, Cosmos DB does not support `LEFT JOIN` or `UNION`. Hence, I'm not sure if you can achieve this in a single query.

Alternatively, you can create a stored procedure to return the desired result.